# want to export this in xml using jaxb but i am getting only last record two times using arraylist java

Tags: jaxb

I want to export this in xml using jaxb but i am getting only last record two times using arraylist java.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?> <ROWS><row> <name>john</name><id>1</id><city>xyz</city></row> <row> <name>monu</name><id>2</id><city>abc</city></row> </rows>
```

Comment: share the JAXB objects and unmarshalling code.

Comment: done this code but now i want to add number of child tags count in xml?? consider here two <row> tag so starting of xml i want to display count as 2 ?

Comment: show your code and tell us what you have done so far. You can click [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/42037841/edit) and add information.